# Is it normal that SPFx Webpart folders are huge

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I've started experimenting with SPFx and going through the tutorials. One thing I realized is that the web part folders are enormous in size. Is this normal?

The basic `HelloWorld` folder created by Yeoman generator is 500MB!

Is this same for everyone or a problem with my environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is completely normal due to upstream dependencies used by SPFx.

You can however reduce this if you the `pnpm` package manager because it reuses the packages.

So, next time you create a new solution, it will check the local file system and will only download packages which are missing otherwise it will link them to your solution.

To use that, you need to install pnpm package manager.

References - [Using pnpm with SPFx](https://www.m365-dev.com/2018/10/31/using-pnpm-with-spfx/)

Comment: thank you so much! do you know how much it reduces? It's just utterly shocking for a helloworld webpart to be that big...

Comment: Yep, plain crazy !!! Its is a significant reduction. Take a look at this video where the number of files reduced from 50,000 to 1000 while using pnpm - 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCwV58BVWMU

Comment: Thanks so much Gautam!

Answer (score 6):

**Yes** this is normal.

This folder size is mostly because of **node_modules** folder in your SPFx project.

If you want to share the SPFx package with anyone, you can share it by excluding the **node_modules** and include all dependencies in `package.json` file.

After sharing it other developers can run `npm install` command in project folder and it will download all dependencies in **node_modules** folder.

**Similar Question**: [The size of the node_modules folder in a project is really big](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/59)

**Other References**:

[Optimize SharePoint Framework builds for production](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/optimize-builds-for-production)

Comment: omg this is plain crazy! Thanks for your answer though!